# "Find" method in Java searching through a linked list is not liking my use of operators

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to put together a method that finds a given object (Pokemon) in my linked list given a String search key. I've been tinkering around with it for an hour or so now and still haven't gotten it to be happy so maybe someone here can shed some light on it.

```
public Pokemon find(String target) {
    PokemonNode cursor = head;
    Pokemon searching = new Pokemon(target, 0, false);
    while (cursor.getLink() != null && !cursor.getData().compareTo(searching)) {
            cursor = cursor.getLink();
    return searching;
    }
    return null;
}
```

at this point, my IDE is complaining about "The operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) int". Any ideas?

Comment: What about using equals instead of compareTo or using !=0 instead of !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `compareTo` method in java returns an `int`, that's why you get the error, as mentioned in the comments you should use the `equals` method. Check this bit of documentation [String compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))